# Getting an error when my plugin is updated, but the files update correctly

Tags: php, plugin-development

I have a plugin that I am using GitHub to manage my updates through the GitHub Releases feature.  Since this is a private plugin I can't put in up in the Wordpress Plugin Directory.

The plugin successfully identifies when a new version is ready from each site it's on.  However, when I click the update now button I get an error:

```
Update failed: <!-- end file --> {"success":true,"data":{"update":"plugin","slug":"plugin-name","oldVersion":"Version 1.0.0","newVersion":"","plugin":"plugin-name\/plugin-name.php","pluginName":"Plugin Name"}}
```

However, if I reload the Plugins page the correct version number is listed and the correct code has been loaded (based on looking at the plugin editor).

Can you please help me understand what is causing this error and perhaps how to set up a success message or something if needed?  ***If additional code from within the plugin is need, please let me know what you need in the comments section.

Comment: how are you doing this? WP doesn't support github releases as a update mechanism out of the box

Comment: I am a really good developer, ha. Plus the use of this article by Matthew Ray: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/08/deploy-wordpress-plugins-with-github-using-transients/